# What is the best method to make an interactive website with MySQL using existing code?

Tags: mysql, html, css

Straight to the point: What is the best method to make an interactive website with a database connection? My current path is to code it all by myself (cue the song). How would you tackle this situation with today’s methods and possibilities?

I already have read into HTML5 and CSS3. I’ve “finished” the homepage with html and wrote the main-css ([here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ashielf/6Lvtdzux/)).The sections on the frontpage should contain elements from the database in the future. The bacon ipsum is just an inadequate place-holder. :P

```
<section>
<h2>Newest entries</h2>
<p>Bacon ipsum ....</p>
```

Currently I’m looking at JS, JQuery and PHP but it’s all relatively new to me. During my studies we looked at JavaEE but I’m unsure if it’s the right approach for this. The [attached diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHAIE.png) shows what classes my website should support. The website should enable collaborative writing of stories between multiple people.

What I would like to know is: Which is the best way to create a functional site? I know one option is to code it all by myself but I have a very strong feeling that all the functionality which I need is already available. Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

My hosting-provider supports MySQL 5, subdomains, Website Redirect, Cronjobs, Domain Mapping in root, Website Directory Indexing, PHP 4, PHP 5 mit SOAP Support, Perl, Python, RealAudio, Ruby 1.8.7, ImageMagick, Ghostscript, Zend Optimizer, Gd

The provider also offers following 1-click installations:

WordPress, Joomla, Concrete 5, bbPress, BuddyPress, Drupal, phpBB2 & 3, Elgg Social Network System, MODX, Vanilla Forums, Pligg Social Networking, Moodle, CMS Made Simple, Piwik, Simple Machines Forum (SMF), Zenphoto, StatusNet, LimeSurvey. MantisBT, PHProjekt, Pixelpost, phpMyFAQ, Textpattern,Open Web Analytics, Geeklog Blog, Nucleus Blog, Mambo CMS,  Locked Area Lite Password Manager, Eblah Online Discussion Forum, TYPO3 Content Management System, Crafty Syntax Live Help, phpCoin Web Hosting Billing System, Revive Adserver, dotProject - Project Management, osTicket - Ticket System, Postcards,Form to Email with CAPTCHA, Custom 404 and 500 Error Pages, Search Engine, Free For All Links page, Banner Advertising System, Online Auction - Just Like eBay, Domain Name Checker, Coppermine Online Photo Gallery, Web Calendar, Web Survey, Gallery2, RoundCube Webmail, MediaWiki, SugarCRM

Looking forward to your recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial or library finding service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to post the wrong question. Could you give me directions to a side where a question like this would be more fitting?

Comment: Checkout yeoman.io , they have tons of cool scaffold projects you could use as well.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will take a look at yeoman.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used Drupal and build some sites with it. It's really powerful and there are a lot of free modules you can use. I'm not sure if there is a module to write collaborative content, but maybe you can tune the workflow module. Anyway if you need it you can code a new module by yourself, but only for the specific functionality you need.

Drupal is very modular and simple, obviously it has a learning curve but I think it is not very hard and it is well documented.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at it. :)